# Using Excel for storing data is better or XML for automation Testing

Tags: xml, excel, watin

I am using WatiN for automation testing. I need to save few values for future reference in my application. I need to know whether Excel is a good approach for storage or I rather use XML for this purpose.

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to store the values go for an XML solution. It will give you the most flexibility to use the collected data later on.

If you need a good visualization then go for Excel where you can apply sorting and filtering and also have the possibility to create graphs.

You can also use a combination of both, i.e. save your data in XML and then import the data into Excel using the XML map feature.